# How to stretch background image of a div

Tags: jquery, css, image, background

I have resizable divs with background images, and contrary to usual needs, I would like the background to stretch and fill the div when it is resized. How would I achieve this? I was thinking about adding an img element inside the div, but I am not sure how, because the divs are created dynamically with a button:

```
$("#add-shape-btn").click(function() {
  const newShape = $("<div>")
    .addClass("shape")
    .attr("id", `shape-${Date.now()}`)
    .appendTo("#shapes-container");
  makeResizable(newShape); // Make the new shape resizable
  makeDraggable(newShape); // Make the new shape draggable
  const shapeId = newShape.attr("id");
  createShapeInfo(shapeId);
  saveShapeData();
});
```

Solution to either problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit] create a [mcve]. Read [ask].

Comment: Sounds like you just need `background-size: cover`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size